# Properly bind comment nodes from xml using XPath

Tags: wpf, xaml, xpath

So I have a tree view that is bound to a dynamically loaded xml file.

Then, in another panel, I have a list view that is bound to the TreeViewItems.

The behavior is that when the user clicks on an item in the tree, then any attributes or text are presented in the ListView.

Given the following xml

```
<Root>
  <Child Name="Attribute">
    <!--Comment-->
    <Content>Some text</Content>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

I get this in my tree, which is exactly as I want.

[image]

This is the binding I'm using to bind the TreeViewItems to the ListView

```
<Binding XPath="@*|text()|comment()" />
```

This works as expected, but not as I would like :).

It renders comments as attributes of their parent, so that if I click the tree node `Child`, I'll see both `Content` and `Comment`.

[image]

But if I click the `Comment` node itself in the tree I get nothing

[image]

This is not as I want.  I prefer that if I click the `Child` node, I get only attributes and text--not commnets, but if I click the `Comment` node, then I should be presented the value of the comment in the ListView.

I'm pretty sure the secret lies in xPath trickery, but I've not been able to get it right.

Changing the binding to

```
<Binding XPath="@*|text()|//comment()" />
```

adds the value of the Comment to the `Comment` node (good), but to every other node in the tree as well (bad).  I've tried throwing in some `not()` conditions on the binding but to no avail.

Changing the binding to

```
<Binding XPath="@*|text()|../comment()" />
```

comes closer, as it then properly binds the comment to the comment node, but aslo to any other children of the node containing the comment.

What I need (I think) is some way of changing this to something like

```
<Binding XPath="@*|text()|../comment()[not(NodeType != Comment)]" />
```

that is, only select this comment it the current context node is a Comment.
But this example fails.

At this point I'm just trying things at random, so I figured it was time to ask:)

Could anyone suggest a binding that would accomplish what I have (hopefully adequately) described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Binding XPath="@*|text()|self::comment()" />
```

Comment: Ha! So beautiful and simple.  Sorry for the late reply, busy on other projects.  Thanks!